# How to fix overlapping boxes in HTML

Tags: html, overlapping

I am making a webstite for my videos, and I am setting up pictures that resemble the video thumbnail.I want there to be 2 pictures per "line". But this is what it looks like:

```
                       -----
                       |   |
                       -----
                              -----
                              |   |
                              -----
```

Each of those boxes that I 'drew' is a box with a picture and a bit of text.

Here is the CSS:

```
#videoList{
width: 480px;
margin: 15px;
background: #DBDBDC;
float: left;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
text-indent: 20px;
}
#videoList2{
width: 480px;
margin: 15px;
background: #DBDBDC;
float: right;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
text-indent: 20px;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="videoList">
                <p>
                <a href="something.html">video title</a>
                </p>
                <img src="images/img.jpeg" />
            </div>

<div id="videoList2">
                <p>
                <a href="something.html">video title</a>
                </p>
                <img src="images/img.jpeg" />
            </div>
```

Is there anything I can do to get two boxes on line?

Comment: Float them both left, don't clear until AFTER the second element using a third element, just for clearing.

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
CSS>>>

```
#videoList{
width: 480px;
margin: 15px;
background: #DBDBDC;
float: left;
text-align: center;
text-indent: 20px;
}

#videoList2{
width: 480px;
margin: 15px;
background: #DBDBDC;
float: left;
text-align: center;
text-indent: 20px;
}
#videoContainer{width: 1020px; height: 300px; background-color: pink}
```

`

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="videoContainer">
    <div id="videoList">
     <p>
         <a href="something.html">video title</a>
     </p>
     <img src="images/img.jpeg" />
    </div>

   <div id="videoList2">
    <p>
     <a href="something.html">video title</a>
    </p>
    <img src="images/img.jpeg" />
   </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work providing the window is large enough for the two boxes to fit on the same line:

```
<div id="videoList">
            <p>
            <a href="something.html">video title</a>
            </p>
            <img src="images/img.jpeg" />
        </div>
<div id="videoList">
            <p>
            <a href="something.html">video title</a>
            </p>
            <img src="images/img.jpeg" />
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #videoList{
       display: block-inline;
       width: 480px;
       margin: 15px;
       background: #DBDBDC;
       float: left;
       text-align: center;
       text-indent: 20px;
       }
```

I added "display: block-inline;" and removed your "clear: both;"
"clear: both;" is similar to "float" but tends to push things bellow

display: block-inline; is to do with making things behave as text, and text will display across the page as opposed to down the page.